# LINQ Max Date with group by

Tags: linq

I have a requirement to sort a list by 1) the number of times a distinct item appears and then 2) if the count of two distinct rows is the same, the most recently used date of that group.

My group by function and sorting by count is working without the date:

```
(from x in data
group x by new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3} 
into g
let count = g.Count()
select new
{
    g.Key.Col1,
    g.Key.Col2,
    g.Key.Col3,
    count
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.count)
```

However, I have been unable to successfully add the date sort.  I was trying to add the date column as an aggregate in the group by expression, but that doesn't work.

```
(from x in data
group x by new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3, MaxDate = x.CreatedDateTime.Max()}
into g
let count = g.Count()
select new
{
    g.Key.Col1,
    g.Key.Col2,
    g.Key.Col3,
    count,
    g.Key.MaxDate
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.count).ThenByDescending(x => x.MaxDate)
```

I get why it doesn't work, I just can't think of another route to add the secondary sort.  Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for (I think)

```
from x in data
group x by new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3} 
into g
let count = g.Count()
select new
{
    g.Key.Col1,
    g.Key.Col2,
    g.Key.Col3,
    MaxDate = g.Select(x => x.CreatedDateTime)
               .OrderByDescending(d => d).FirstOrDefault(),
    count
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.count).ThenByDescending(x => x.MaxDate)
```

Comment: For MaxDate, this query pulls an entire data row as a type for the MaxDate column.  I'll have to play with it and see if I can narrow that down.

Comment: Yes, your right. What is behind the scenes, anything like linq to sql, entity framework?

Comment: "data" is a custom data IList

Comment: Never mind, I edited it a bit. But the source of your data (like entity framework) may rule out some constructs.

Comment: That works!  Thanks a bunch.  I don't get the ".OrderByDescending(d => d)" part but my LINQ-foo is weak.  I'll have to look it up.

Comment: @NicoleCastle The previous Select for MaxDate results in a collection of whatever the type of `CreatedDateTime` is (assuming DateTime).  So When you order it, you don't have to select a property as usual, you just order it by the value of each item (d => d).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    var ordered = Elev8SnaTowelTables
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 })
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .ThenByDescending(g => g.Max(x => x.CreatedDateTime));
```