# How do I group on one of two possible fields using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying to get the latest contact with a given user, grouped by user:

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public string SentTo { get; set; }
    public string SentFrom { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public string SendDate { get; set; }
}
```

The user's contact info could either be in `SentTo` or `SentFrom`.

```
List<ChatMessage> ecml = new List<ChatMessage>();
var q = ecml.OrderByDescending(m => m.SendDate).First();
```

would give me the latest message, but I need the last message per user.
The closest solution I could find was [LINQ Max Date with group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969539/linq-max-date-with-group-by), but I cant seem to figure out the correct syntax. I would rather not create multiple List objects if I don't have to. 
If the user's info is in `SentTo`, my info will be in `SentFrom`, and vice-versa, so I do have some way of checking where the user's data is.

Did I mention I was very new to LINQ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `GroupBy` user, then `.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.SendDate).First();`

Comment: You can always make 2 separate queries, firstwith user in SentTo, second with user in SentFrom and then take max from one of this two.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but how do you group by SentTo OR SentFrom in the same statement? Is it even possible, or do I need to copy the list and modify it to combine the fields, then group the new list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to interpret each record twice - i.e. as a `SentTo` and a `SentFrom`, the query becomes a bit tricky:

```
var res = ecml
    .SelectMany(m => new[] {
        new { User = m.SentFrom, m.SendDate }
    ,   new { User = m.SentTo, m.SendDate }
    })
    .GroupBy(p => p.User)
    .Select(g => new {
        User = g.Key
    ,   Last = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.SendDate).First()
    });
```

The key trick is in `SelectMany`, which makes each `ChatMessage` item into two anonymous items - one that pairs up the `SentFrom` user with `SendDate`, and one that pairs up the `SentTo` user with the same date.

Once you have both records in an enumerable, the rest is straightforward: you group by the user, and then apply the query from your post to each group.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy, look at this code:

```
string username = "John";
var q = ecml.Where(i=>i.SentFrom == username || i.SentTo == username).OrderByDescending(m => m.SendDate).First();
```

It simply filter your collection be choosing items which either SentFrom or SentTo is equal to `username`.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question